# Codeigniter form post 403

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-403

I can't submit a form using Codeigniter 3.1.6 because I am getting [403 Forbidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RogCp.png)

POST data doesn't go to `revise/updates`. My form from other page is working perfectly except this one. I am not using AJAX.

**View**

```
<?=form_open('revise/updates');?>
   <input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$lead[0]['name'];?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$lead[0]['id'];?>">
   <input type="email" name="email" value="<?=$lead[0]['email'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="contact" value="<?=$lead[0]['phone_number'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="company" value="<?=$lead[0]['comp_name'];?>">
   <input type="text" name="va"  value="<?=$lead[0]['va'];?>" readonly>
   <input type="text" name="sales"  value="<?=$lead[0]['sales_name'];?>" readonly>
   <input type="text" name="service"  value="<?=$lead[0]['service_name'];?>" readonly>
   <textarea name="note"><?=$lead[0]['note'];?></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" name="opt" value="yes">
   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="1">
   <button type="submit" name="submit">Confirm</button>
<?=form_close();?>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Revise extends VA_Controller {

   function __construct () {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');
   }

    public function index($array)
    {
      $this->load->view('header');
      $this->load->view('update-lead',$array);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

   public function updates() {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact', 'Contact', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', 'Company Name', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('service', 'Service', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('va', 'vAmbassador', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('sales', 'Sales Person', 'trim|required');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('note', 'note', 'trim');

      if($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
         echo "OK";
      }
      else {
         echo "Some Error";
      }
   }
}
```

I have .htaccess file as per mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file)

Comment: its my guess only, i think you cant create new class or controller with `Update` because its already predefined class or controller in codeigniter.

Comment: @Ayyappaamara I changed the class name but I still get the error.

Comment: can you please post your full controller page

Comment: @Ayyappaamara I updated the question

Comment: what is the `VA_Controller`? is it custom controller? have you loaded this one in `config/autoload.php`?

Comment: `VA_Controller` is a custom controller that checks the session. I put it inside `application/core/`. It extends `CI_Controller`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161178/discussion-between-ayyappa-amara-and-rey).

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You have to remove your `index.php` entry from your `/application/config/config.php`

Verify that is setup correctly the 403 forbidden error might be due to a faulty `.htaccess` rewrite.

Comment: I already have .htaccess
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>`

and index.php is also omitted on config.php

Comment: @Rey take backup of current file and replace this.

Comment: I tried it but it redirects to the home page.

This is the link of the form
`example.com/folder/admin/update`

Comment: @Rey then may be you should try a different name as there are chances that `update` keyword is used by codeigniter itself.

Comment: I changed the class name but I still get the error.

Comment: @Rey what is `VA_contoller`? try replacing `VA_Controller` with `CI_Controller `.

Comment: I created another controller `VA_Controller` that checks the session. It extends `CI_Controller`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to modifi your existing controller like below code.

```
class Revise extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct () {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper('form');
      $this->load->library('form_validation');

      if(!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"]) && !isset($_SESSION["username"]) && $_SESSION["logged_in"] !== TRUE && $_SESSION["username"] !== 'example@example.com' ) 
      {
        redirect('/login');
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d